# WinSCP password with percent sign in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, winscp

Py remote PC [whose login password cannot be changed] has few special characters, notably the percent sign (`%`). So WinSCP script that i have written is unable to log in.

As per [this document](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url), I tried to the following, but I couldn't get any success.

My password is `admin%^&`. I followed the above document and modified the password like this `admin%25^&`.

How do I escape special character for WinSCP to log in?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\!Y!M!D_Log.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open  sftp://admin:admin%25^&@137.55.111.1" ^
    "put *.* %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` and `&` do not really need to be encoded (while it does not do any harm). The `%` does, what you correctly did as `%25`. It would work, if specified on WinSCP command-line directly. The actual problem is that the `%` has a special meaning also *in a batch file*, not only in WinSCP. `%2` is replaced by the second parameter of the batch file, even before WinSCP is started. If no (second) parameter is provided to the batch file, WinSCP sees `admin5^&` (`%2` is gone).

If you want to use `%` literally in a batch file, you need to double it: `admin%%25^&`.

Easy way is to have [WinSCP GUI generate a batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) (note that it will [unnecessarily] encode even `^` and `&`).

This is covered in WinSCP FAQ [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file#percent)

Answer (score -1):

the answer is u need to see the UTF-8 chart and replace the char.

so admin%^& is now admin%25%5e%26

Comment: That's not the correct answer. `admin%25%5e%26` won't work, WinSCP will see the password as `admin5e6`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is working. when you put this in batch file.

Comment: No it's not. If I put this to a batch file: `"open  sftp://admin:admin%25%5e%26@137.55.111.1" ^` and enable password logging (`/loglevel=* /log=winscp.log`), I see this in the log file: `Password: admin5e6` (as expected) - If it is working for you, it must be because your password is actually `admin5e6` and not `admin%^&` - All assuming you are using latest/recent version of WinSCP. - Thanks for accepting my answer, btw :)

Comment: Share your log file. and it also could be for 2 reason i suspect. either your batch log file is interpreting in this order as this special character escaping is for winscp cmd line login only.
this is what my log file shows- '"/ini=nul" "/command" "open sftp://admin:***@137.55.124.177" . notice password area is has been masked while loging.

Comment: It's not "batch log file". It's WinSCP log file. It logs the exact password that WinSCP is going to use for authentication. Did you use `/loglevel=*`? If you did, and still got `***`, it must be because you are not using a recent version of WinSCP.